# "You can only post once every 60 minutes" - How come it wasn't 40 minutes?

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

Low-rep users are rate-limited to 1 question every 40 minutes (90 minutes on Stack Overflow) network-wide. I tried to submit a question here on WebApps.StackExchange, but I got the following error:

> You can only post once every 60 minutes.

60 minutes? I searched all over Meta Stack Exchange, but nowhere does it mention a case where the time limit is 60 minutes instead of the usual 40.

What was the cause of that?

Comment: I wonder if that changed recently.